# Who is the speaker in Psalm 45:6 and who is its subject? God or a human king?

Tags: referent-identification, messiah

JPS Tanakh 1917
Thy throne given of God is for ever and ever; A sceptre of equity is the sceptre of thy kingdom.

Who is the speaker in Psalm 45:6 and who is its subject? God or a human king? Does this verse have 2 fulfillment?

Comment: @Dottard.The link you suggested does not ask who the speaker is.

Comment: Ahh Alex - see Perry's answer below.  It is only unclear to those who do not want to see.

Answer (score 3):

If you take the New Testament as authoritative it's the Father speaking to the Son.

> For to which of the angels did God ever say, ...
> (Heb 1:5, ESV)

> 8 But of the Son he says,

```
              “Your throne, O God, is forever and ever, 
  the scepter of uprightness is the scepter of your kingdom. 
        9       You have loved righteousness and hated wickedness; 
              therefore God, your God, has anointed you 
  with the oil of gladness beyond your companions.” 
                  (Heb 1:8–9, ESV)
```

> 31 And behold, you will conceive in your womb and bear a son, and you shall call his name Jesus. 32 He will be great and will be called the Son of the Most High. And the Lord God will give to him the throne of his father David, 33 and he will reign over the house of Jacob forever, and of his kingdom there will be no end.”
> (Luk. 1:31–33, ESV)

Comment: Thanks for this - saved me the trouble.  +1.  Good answer.